# Find and Replace text in html file

Tags: c#, html, winforms, file

I am working with Winforms in C#. i have following Html File.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p><b>Chapter 1</b></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And i want to replace `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />` with `"<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=""+ htmlFile +"" />"`
I have tried the following code but it doesnt work

```
 string outpageFile = File.ReadAllText(StaticClass.outpage);
            string htmlFile= StaticClass.ZipFilePath + "\\OEBPS\\styles.css";
            outpageFile = outpageFile.Replace("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css' />", "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='"+ htmlFile +"' />");
            File.WriteAllText(StaticClass.outpage, outpageFile);
```

But it din't work. Main Problem is occuring in double inverted commas that are being used. How to do it then ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HtmlAgility pack (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - regex isn't the best way how to deal with replacements in html.

Example:

```
      string markup = @"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""
    ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"">
<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
<head>
<meta name=""generator"" content=""HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org"" />
<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=us-ascii"" />
<link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href=""styles.css"" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p><b>Chapter 1</b></p>
</body>
</html>";
      var html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
      html.LoadHtml(markup);
      var links = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link");
      foreach (var link in links) {
        link.Attributes["href"].Value = StaticClass.ZipFilePath +
          "\\OEBPS\\styles.css";
      }

      var builder = new StringBuilder();
      using (var writer = new StringWriter(builder)) {
        html.Save(writer);
      }
      markup = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks for your immediate reply but i dont want to use any external package. I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: @user - are you sure your html will adhere to some standards ? <link href=style.css"> or <link href  =  "style.css" /> are also options - that's why HtmlAgilityPack is better when it comes to do replaces in html as it can deal with lot of crazy stuff, even quirky html ...

Comment: but if we have added javascripts file also in our html and we have added their link also.. In that case it will replace their href attribute also, which we dont want.

Comment: @user - have you actually tried my code ? Javascript starts <script> not with <link> - which I'm searching for; and you can always check type or rel attribute of the link.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is you will have a dynamic HTML page  url in the LINK.
Why you should try to change the entire link.

Try this. In your HTML make the LINK something like below which will be unique in your page and replace that particular string alone with your new LINK.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='@MYLINK' />
```

In application

```
filenamestring.replace("@MYLINK","http://www.google.com");
```

This should work perfectly

Comment: but it will replace all the occurences of "@MYLINK" in whole file.. But we need to replace only at this point... We can have more than one occurences of "@MYLINK" in our file..

Comment: Hey man. Make a unique Name like "@MYLINK1" and "@MYLINK1" should not be written anywhere else? Dont make things complex. Just be simple.